# Sync dropdown cells and edit it

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Sorry English is not my native language but I can't find anything to this topic and I hope you understand my writing/problem and can help me.

I have a huge google sheet with many columns. But for this I create an example like there are only A (Names) and B (Age) important and lets say it is Sheet 2. I don't want to look through all of this every time when I do some changes. So I created a sheet 1. There I have in cell A1 a dropdown list for the names and when I select a name then there should be in cell B1 the age of that person - that would be possible with vlookup, yes yes. But I want that it is possible to edit cell b1 and then it should update this persons age in the sheet 2.

For example I have John in sheet 2 and he is 45. Now I go to sheet 1 and select John with my dropdown list in A1 and in B1 it says 45. Now I change 45 into 46 and in sheet 2 John should now be 46.

I know that I need a script for that because with a formula it is not possible to edit numbers, but I don't have any clue how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Sheet 2 can use [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en). For example, in sheet 2, A2 = `John` and B2 = `=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A:B,2,FALSE)`

Comment: yes I can do that, but then I have by every other persons age #NV and only the right age by john. And If I change the person, then John has #NV and the other person has this age written. So with this I can't overwrite the current written age and save it permanently.